# Setting a cell delegate in swift gives error

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview

I am trying to use [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) library to make custom swipe cell. However, `cell.delegate = self` keep giving me error saying that

> "Cannot assign value of type 'AlarmTableViewController' to type 'MGSwipeTableCellDelegate?'"

but even if I insert 'as! MGSwipeTableCellDelegate' it makes fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
class AlarmTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifier = "programmaticCell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MGSwipeTableCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = "Title"
        cell.delegate = self as! MGSwipeTableCellDelegate //optional
        return cell
    }
}
```

In my storyboard I've set cell's custom class as `MGSwipeTableCell` and its identifier as `programmaticCell`. Please help me. `tableView` is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `MGSwipeTableCellDelegate` the delegate for your class.

```
class AlarmTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MGSwipeTableCellDelegate
```

and the reason for your crash is force `as!` conversion while its nil.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TheTiger’s answer. But I would also consider this option which is to use an extension rather than add it to the main brackets.

```
extension SomeType: SomeProtocol, AnotherProtocol {
    // implementation of protocol requirements goes here
}
```

Or in your case it would be

```
extension AlarmTableViewController: MGSwipeTableCellViewDelegate {
    //and then you can add all the methods here if any
}
```

This is slightly better because you can then add all the methods together in a more clear way. By splitting it up by the different delegations it will be better when you go back and need to change something

Some reading if you’re interested: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Also if this isn’t clear you add in any file, but it would be best to add it at the bottom of your file with the `AlarmTableViewController`.